# can no longer connect to PostgreSQL in VirtualBox

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, operating-system, virtualbox

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports), OS X 10.12.6, VirtualBox 5.2.22

I have a VirtualBox snapshot of PostgreSQL 9.2.23 running in CentOS 7.4.1708 that I saved a year ago. At that time, I could connect to it from the host Mac using Razor SQL and other applications. I restored it several times since then and it worked fine.

I restored it again this week and can no longer connect using Razor SQL. I can ping the instance's IP address, ssh into it, and use psql. The VM's IP address has not changed and PostgreSQL is still using port 5432.

The VM is using a bridged adapter. The physical adapter has changed, I switched to a different dock. Switching the adapter to the built-in WiFi has no effect.

pg_hba.conf settings:

```
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

postgresql.conf connections and authentication settings:

```
listen_addresses = '*'              # what IP address(es) to listen on;
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

relevant netstat output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20039    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

ifconfig in the VM:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.53  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::126f:f1a8:7d36:a935  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a0:df:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 660271  bytes 990475536 (944.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 265677  bytes 17771022 (16.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

firewall:

```
[root@localhost robert]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68

[root@localhost robert]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you connect to postgres from the VirtualBox Machine?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can ssh in and use psql. Or I can log on to the VM and use the local terminal.

Comment: Then is probably a firewall thing. Check your pc to see if have a rule for port 5432

Comment: I forgot to say that the firewall is disabled.

Comment: firewall disable on both pc?

Comment: The host's firewall is disabled.

Comment: And the client firewall?

Comment: As shown above, the CentOS firewall in the VM is disabled.